# How to make a Lordif plot in black and white

Tags: r, plot

I've successfully created a plot from the lordif function in R for visualizing items flagged for differential item functioning. However, the default settings make use of a red color. Is there a way to produce black and white plots from this object?

I have tried to add a col = black option but this does not work. bwtheme <- standard.theme("pdf", color=FALSE) also doesn't work.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible [MRE] so others can run using copy & paste. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with library() , this makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time the package has been updated with BW = TRUE argument to plot in black and white.

plot(lordifObject, labels = c('labelA', labelB'),BW = TRUE)